# Playing Scale and Alpha Animations at the same time

Tags: animation, game-engine, transparency

I animate a sphere changing scale(frame 1 to 60)
And also his Alpha value(frame 1 to 60)

When playing booth through actions acutators(one for each, linked by an always sensos), just scale play. alpha dont change.

testing alpha alone, work well. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The channels are separate ... I would expect it to be fine.I really can't tell why it does not play.

I suggest to play them at different animation layers.

[image]